# How to massively deploy a web application to 100+ server?

Tags: deployment

Let's say I have a web application in nodejs or php and I want to deploy to 100+ server, also to push application updates without destroying the data ..

I have been reading about a lot of things like configuration management systems like chef, containerization && micro-services via docker..

But I didn't grasp how to use these tools to do what I want or even if there are better tools than it.
So I ask for a guidance, anything will  be appreciated.

Note : one server will have a clone of the application with a few customization for each client.

Comment: You have listed some of the most popular tools used to achieve your desired outcome. I suggest learning at least one first, this will help understand the others.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor I have been reading about them for more than a week, but the result is almost nothing .. 
I am kinda confused which tool do what

Comment: Your requirement seems rather straightforward. Checkout [kwatee](http://kwatee.net) (disclaimer: I am the creator). It may do exactly what you need with a minimal learning curve.